# accessing facebook api gives unauthorised access error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, api

I am hitting

```
https://www.facebook.com/company/{companyid}/scim/Users
```

this url with headers as

```
Authorization: bearer {accessToken}.
```

When i access it using postman it gives me result. But when i access it using

```
$.ajax({  
            url: URL, 
            type: "GET",  
            dataType: "jsonp",

            beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer access_token');}
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("innnnn");
                console.log(data);
            },  
            error: function (error) {  

            }  
        });
```

using this code it gives me error: Unauthorised access. Access to this resource is forbidden

Comment: Where are you sending access token?

Comment: Bearer access_token in this access_token is access token value